# Spring Cloud Ribbon concurrent TimeoutException

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We are setting up the Spring Cloud suite of projects (config, discovery, hystrix, etc.)

Lately, however, all of the ribbon calls are failing.  I can see in the logs the microservices are being called correctly and returning their appropriate responses. Zuul is then throwing a forwarding error. Digging through the stacktrace it looks like ribbon is failing with a concurrent TimeoutException.

This only just started.  Not sure if it is an incompatibility with Java 1.8.0_66 or a Spring Cloud dependency has received an update that is causing this.

Exception:

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:105)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:84)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:111)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:295)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: servicemanagerRibbonCommand timed-out and no fallback available.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:807)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:794)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:77)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1516)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1406)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:314)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:306)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:144)
    at rx.Observable$1.call(Observable.java:136)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7531)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:78)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:953)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:973)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:610)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$9.call(AbstractCommand.java:591)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:77)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I should also mention this is Spring Boot 1.2.6, Spring Cloud Netflix 1.0.3.  There were no code changes, just revisiting the app and ribbon calls fail.

Comment: I have gone through the steps to migrate these apps to Spring Boot 1.3, Spring Cloud Brixton.M3, and the same issue exists.

Comment: A `TimeoutException` doesn't tell me much. I can't even make a guess. I'm assuming you can hit the services individually without problem? Have you changed any timeout values in configuration?

Comment: @spencergibb I will grab any debugging details and post it here.  But these apps are pretty vanilla and when I originally posted this, there were no code changes.  The only thing I am aware of was java on my laptop was updated. I also spun these up in docker as well and received the same exception, which leads me to think there is an issue with one of the libraries, since the docker image was using openjdk.

Comment: Another post I saw somewhere else was this is related to Hystrix setting isolation strategy to SEMAPHORE instead of THREAD.  I have set it to both, but the same issue is still present.

Comment: If you have an app you can share that reproduces the problem, that would be helpful.

Comment: The repos are not public. Let me see if I can find a way to push them somewhere I can give you access.

Comment: i am working on getting approval to share the code with you.  Might just be exported projects in a zip file on dropbox, but we will work something out.

Comment: Maybe just a toy project?

Comment: In creating a toy app, I cannot reproduce the issue in the new app. It has to be a configuration issue at this point.  I will compare my 2 projects for differences and update this issue when I find the mismatch

Comment: Thanks! That will be helpful.

Comment: @spencergibb I am not sure I quite understand what is going on here. Originally created one project to house both Zuul rules and Hystrix Circuit Breaker.  So, basically, when a Zuul rule would get applied, it would just redirect back onto a controller in the same project, then make calls to the remote microserver, with a hystrix fallback should all instances of the microserver go away. When I break the hystrix piece out into a separate service, I don't get these issues, and they seem to recover more cleanly as I start and stop instances of the microservice.  Does that make sense?

Comment: One more thing I have found, this ZuulException: forwarding error seems to get thrown in the first minute the service is up, eureka probably hasn't updated its service routes yet. After about a minute or so, it will recover.

Comment: that is the normal behavior of ribbon and eureka.